# If no message in windows application message queue, then will message loop still continuously runs?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, sdk, windows-messages

I have a doubt about windows message queue, and message loop.
Could any one help me in understanding, or pls provide some reference links.

If no message in windows application message queue, then will message loop still continuously runs?

If runs then, does application get hangs? since loop is continuously happening? How does it works?

Thanks,
hara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetMessage()` will block until a message arrives on the queue.

This quote:

*If the queue is empty, the function blocks until another message is queued.*

is from [Window Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. you helped me with very good link. :) tnx. hara

Comment: Essentially, as there is no message, there is nothing for your UI thread to do at all. Mouse moves, timers, any form of user interaction cause messages and your UI thread to "wake up".

Comment: But note that Windows will send dummy WM_PAINT messages from time to time, even if there's nothing to paint. See here for why that is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/27/561924.aspx